# webpack localhost/sockjs.js.map not found

Tags: javascript, react, webpack

Estou com o seguinte erro referente a socks.js.map, alguém pode me ajudar ?

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

instalei a versão mais recente do webpack e webpack-dev-server e configurei assim :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry : './index.js',
    output : {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        filename : './bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: './public'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node-modules/,
            query: {
                presets : ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    }

}
```

O meu package.json esta com um script:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline --hot"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se por versão mais recente do webpack significa v2 ou v3, o formato do seu module está errado. Agora se usa `module.rules` em vez de `module.loaders`. É assim agora:

```
  module: {
      rules: [{
          test: /.js?$/,
          exclude: /node-modules/,
          use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                  presets : ['es2015']
              }
          }
      }]
  }
```

(Ref https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules)